# Three light switching (not three way)

Tags: lighting

I have a small situation, A = Outside light, B = Porch light, C = Inside Light.

I would like to switch

- A + B together but not C, and then
- B + C together and not A

Is there a relay or something that would switch between two different control to achieve this ?

Comment: You need a state machine. Easiest way is to make one with a microcontroller though (like an Arduino or PICAXE if you want to keep it simple) you could use a bunch of logic gates and flip flops if you really wanted to.

Comment: what does this mean? ...  `B + C together and not C`

Comment: @jsotola I'm going to guess a copy-paste with incomplete modification

Comment: Not incomplete, I have three lights in total. I would like to control with two switches. In one way I would like A and B to turn on, in another way I could like B and C to be on.

Comment: Is *B* always ON ? Then you only need to decide if either *A* or *C* is ON. Also, is there a case where *all* are OFF ?

Comment: Please draw a truth table.

Comment: Read jsotola's comment again carefully. There's an error in your question.

Comment: "Is there a relay or something" Yeah just use two 2-pole NO relays. Optionally with a memory/latching feature. Specs depend on voltages and currents, AC or DC etc.

Answer (score 4):

As @jsotola pointed out in the comments, "B + C together and not C" does not make sense. Your question also does not define what happens when both switches are on.

If what you want is:

*Table 1. Truth table.*

```
SW1  SW2   A   B   C
Off  Off   0   0   0
On   Off   1   1   0
Off  On    0   1   1
On   On    1   1   1
```

then that can be achieved by two 2-pole switches.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo1HpI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A circuit that gives the switching arrangement of Table 1.*

Comment: If this is electrical wiring to be connected to the mains, the inside light, porch light, and outside light might not be powered by the same circuit breakers, and so it may not be permissible to connect them together.

This circuit can still be used if the wires above the switches connect to the appropriate power wires, and if the neutral wires below the lamps are separated.

Answer (score 1):

A DPDT, centre-off toggle or rocker switch would suffice.

[image]

The 3 positions would be (A & B) on, all off and (B & C) on.